# Limiting probability of a false positive when measuring whether two binary variables correlate

Tags: time-series, correlation, binomial-distribution

Note: I don't have formal training in statistics, so please excuse any mistake I've made in my question.

I have two arrays, each with the time-series data of a binary variable, like this:

```
A: 001101011010100100101001...
B: 100101000101001100101101...
```

The time-series are of length $N$ (they can vary). (**Edit:** Thanks to @Mai for pointing out that I've said "time-series" here, but I only care about their "spatial" correlations, so the samples for each time-step can be treated as independent samples.)

The goal is to determine whether $A$ and $B$ correlate (negative or positive) with one another or not, but to limit the chance of a false positive to $0.0001\%$ (for example). This obviously means raising the probability of a false negative - and that's fine for my use case. Also, to be clear, I don't care about the strength of the correlation - only whether or not they correlate at all.

A simple approach would be to look at the difference between $P(A|B)$ and $P(A)$. If there is a difference, then they correlate. This obviously will give a lot of false positives, since the time-series are of length $N$, which is finite.

So I had the idea that I'd get the absolute value of the difference between $P(A|B)$ and $P(A)$, and then subtract the maximum absolute difference that we'd "expect" to see between those values in $99.9999\%$ of experiments between two *independent* binary variables with $P(A)$ and $P(B)$ where the time-series are of length $N$. As far as I can see, that would cause the probability of a false positive to be $0.0001\%$.

Is this a reasonable approach? Is there a simpler way? I'm actually dealing with trillions of pairs of binary variables, and so performance is a consideration. If I went with the above approach, then I think I'd need to use a combination of normal and poisson approximations to the binomial distribution to be able to handle the full range of $N$ and $p$ values. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do this with a [chi-squared test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_test) or [Fishers exact test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_exact_test)!

Just collapse your data to the needed format:

[image]

With the chi-squared test you can calculate the probability that your 2 measurements are independent or not. I think this is what you want to know.

Comment: I think the fact that they are time series implies they are not sequences of independent trials. Not sure.

Comment: Thanks! This seems like just what I'm after! @Mai I have updated the post to clarify that the samples can be treated independently - thanks!